# Issue with passing pointer-to-a-pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm passing crazy amounts of pointers in my C program and I need help to figure out if I'm doing it right.

I declare a pointer to an array structures (containing 3 fields, 1, the relevant one, is an integer):

```
StatusItem* statusItem = NULL;
```

Pass a pointer to a pointer of the array to a function:

```
parse_object(..., &statusItem, ...)
```

It is read into the function:

```
parse_object(..., StatusItem** statusItem, ...)
```

Memory is allocated:

```
*statusItem = malloc(cJSON_GetArraySize(*items) * sizeof(StatusItem));
```

A component (the integer field of one of the indices) of it is passed to ANOTHER function:

```
parseInt((*optional)->valuestring, &statusItem[i]->optional)
```

This is the function, and this is where I'm getting an error.  Somehow, I am not passing the reference to the array index correctly:

```
bool parseInt(char *num, int *result)
{
    char *end;

    int val = strtol(num, &end, 10);
    if(errno == ERANGE || *end != '\0')  // checks that given value was a number
    {
        return false;
    }
    *result = val;
    return true;
}
```

I know it's really confusing, but I don't think I can help that.  Please ask for clarification where needed.

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly what error you're getting? Compiler, runtime, exact wording? optional is int *, right?

Comment: What is the result you are seeing and what result do you expect?

Comment: You need to pass the address. From what I see, probably `&(*statusItem)[i].optional`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett runtime error.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I want it to just pass back the number to be stored, and its saying it cannot access the memory

Comment: strtol() is for long int. and not for int. If you want to simply convert to int, use   atoi()

Comment: @DennyMathew atoi sucks for checking for failure.

Comment: Your memory allocation should be `statusItem = malloc(cJSON_GetArraySize(*items) * sizeof(StatusItem));` (without the `*` before statusItem), and the function call : `parseInt((your_arg)->valuestring, &statusItem[i].the_int_field);`

Comment: @rerito: No, he's doing that right (it's a double pointer)

Comment: @SuvP: that's the operator precedence anyway (right to left)

Comment: @DanielFischer That worked, but for some reason my arrays arent storing more than 1 value.  They don't fail when trying to access further elements, but they don't store values

Comment: @Nealon To diagnose that, we'd need to see more code. The definition of the type, and where the array is filled.

Comment: @Nealon when I was learning C I found it helpful to deal with multiple indirection by declaring less-indirected local pointers and assigning to those, so I only had to get my brain around one level of indirection at a time. I'd try getting a pointer to the first item in your array, then increment that pointer n times. Once you get that working, work your way back up piece by piece to an expression that does all the indirections in one whack. Sounds silly, but I found it helped.

Comment: @Nicholaz : You mean allocation and the parseInt call occur in the parse_object function ? At first reading, I thought they were just following the `statusItem` declaration (which is a "simple" pointer).

Comment: A good advice should to learn how to use a debugger. Doing so, you could track the variables values step by step and see if they are in the expected state.

Comment: @DanielFischer I got it figured out, it was an issue with another malloc later on.  Thank you.  If you post your comment as an answer I'll give you credit.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Definitely a good tip, all this indirection is making my head hurt XD

Comment: @rerito: yes, inside the parse item where it is a double-ptr.  But I now see the way you interpreted it (in that light your comment would make sense)

Comment: @DennyMathew The `atoi()` function is _defined in terms of `strtol()`_, the only significant difference being that an error with `atoi()` explicitly results in Undefined Behavior. I cannot in good faith recommend using `atoi()`. Ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the address of the field to be set to `parseInt`, from what we can see, the address of a `StatusItem*` being passed to `parse_object`, and the allocation being

```
*statusItem = malloc(cJSON_GetArraySize(*items) * sizeof(StatusItem));
```

it will probably be

```
&(*statusItem)[i].optional
```

The `(*statusItem)` gives you the pointer to the allocated memory, the indexing `(*statusItem)[i]` then accesses the `i`-th of the allocated `StatusItem` objects, and then its `optional` field is selected before finally the address of that is taken.